# Passwordless ssh between two nodes, but the authorized_keys file is on a shared filesystem (GPFS)

Tags: linux, ssh

so I have two servers. On these servers /dev/sdb is a disk that has been used for a shared filesystem (i.e, both servers put their second harddrives "together" and now each one can use all the space as if it was local to them)

There is a user, db2inst1 that has a home directory on this shared system- I can't generate a private key file on each server and put the id_rsa.pub stuff into authorized_keys because every time ssh-keygen is run it overwrites the id_rsa files.

How can I get passwordless ssh between these two nodes? I've already tried putting the same line twice in authorized_keys- only changing the server name at the end- but this doesn't seem to work. Permissions are 600.

Ideas?

Comment: What are the perms on the parent directories?  Both ~/.ssh and ~?

Comment: 700 on .ssh and 777 on ~ (yeah I know that isn't the best.)

Comment: Well there's your problem.  ssh will not accept any files under 
~/.ssh if ~ is even group writable.

Comment: What should the permissions be on the ~ directory? 700 as well? I just tried 755 but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Public/private keypairs aren't tied to a hostname. The hostname you might see at the end of a public key entry is just a comment, and is ignored.

In principle, all you should need to do is add the `id_rsa.pub` contents into `authorized_keys` once. Both `db2inst1` users should be reading from the corresponding `id_rsa` private key file, and then seeing that the associated public key is in `authorized_keys`.

Use `ssh -v` to verify that the correct private key file is being read, and that the read is successful.

Comment: I tried making a new key and only placing that in authorized_keys but it didn't quite workout. Here is output from ssh -v http://pastebin.com/KyCDJQFR